# CAS serviceValidate not returning JSON

Tags: cas

I am using CAS 3.5.2. I am trying to call the serviceValidate in CAS passing the "ticket","service" and "format=JSON"(optional parameter). As per CAS 3.0 spec the format parameter specifies the format in which the response will be returned. But even after specifying the format as JSON, i am still getting XML response.

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is not supported in cas 3.5

Comment: ok thanks. Please let me know the version that supports this behavior.

Comment: 4.2 and above, I believe. Also see https://apereo.github.io/cas/developer/Maintenance-Policy.html